# Show & hide bottom aligned, content only scroll

Tags: jquery, hide, show

i am trying to get a same functionality used @ http://bit.ly/99a5El

header& footer is sticky, when user clicks down arrow, you can observe the box is going down at the same time page scroll also changes

i request anyone please help me... thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your demo do the changes below.

In CSS:

```
#content {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top:200px;
  width: 700px;
  text-align:left;
  z-index:1;
  position: relative;
}

#layout {
  width: 700px;
  position:absolute;
}
```

The complete JS file:

```
<!-- Function -->
var positionClosed = 0; // the vertical position of the title when minimized
 $(function(){
  positionClosed = $(window).height() - // window size
    $('#footer').height() - // footer size
    $('#content').css('margin-top').replace('px', '') - // margin from top
    $('.trigger').height() - // title size
    20; // a little margin

  $("#content").css('top', positionClosed);
  $('.toggle_container').hide();

  $(".trigger").click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass("active").next().slideToggle("slow");
    if(!$(this).hasClass('active'))  
      $('#content').animate({top: 0}, 'slow');
    else
     $('#content').animate({top: positionClosed}, 'slow');
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `position:fixed` in CSS files for the header and footer with `bottom:0px` for the footer and `top:0px` for the header.

Comment: i have a try as mentioned but no use here is the demo link @ http://bit.ly/vy0lO5 when content is hided the title should go bottom of the page smoothly...